# MATLAB does not recognize".m" file changes after switching branches in git

Tags: git, matlab

MATLAB does not recognize  changes to files when I change git branched. 
To fix the issue I have to run first run the code in debug mode and after that every thing will be OK.

Is there a way to force MATLAB to not cache the files in memory and read from drive so that this does not happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear a specific function/script from memory and force Matlab to re-read it from disk:

```
clear myfun
```

To clear *all* functions/scripts from memory:

```
clear functions
```

This should allow you to `git branch` without an issue.

For more detail see [documentation here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html#inputarg_ItemType). Note that `clear all` accomplishes this same task but the expense of clearing all variables in the workspace etc.

Comment: I had clear in my initial script and by changing to clear all, works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Note that if you are creating MATLAB classes, you'll need to use `clear classes` - weirdly, `clear classes` does everything that `clear all` does (variables, scripts, functions), plus also clears class definitions. You'd think all would mean all, but no.

Answer (score 2):

If MATLAB doesn't recognize changes in files it needs to refresh the caches and you can do that using [`rehash`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rehash.html) command:

```
rehash path
```

should solve your problem.